# How to replace $ when converting JSON object to c# with out actually changing the name of that particular field in which $ exists?

Tags: json, c#-4.0

When I'm converting Json objects to c#, I got an issue In which my Json has fields with $ symbol(ex: $t).But c# doesn't accept fields with special characters. If i try to replace $ with any other letters in my c# code, I'm unable to get data from 3rd party because of the change in naming.

How can I solve this issue?

Json string:

```
"author": [(1)
{
"name": {
"$t": "theabctv"
},-
"uri": {
 $t": "http://gdata.abc.com/feeds/api/users/theabctv"
},-
"yt$userId": {
"$t": "tCUABCCT7wYG1PMCpw"
}-
}-
],-
```

C# code:-

```
public class Author2

{

public Name2 name { get; set; }
public Uri2 uri { get; set; }
public YtUserId __invalid_name__yt$userId { get; set; }
}
public class Name2
{
public string __invalid_name__$t { get; set; }
}

public class Uri2
{
public string __invalid_name__$t { get; set; }
}

public class YtUserId
{
public string __invalid_name__$t { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to declare property names with symbols in NET framework, meaning that you cant have isomorphism between the JSON objects and the C# objects without parsing the JSON data. You could replace all $ symbol with any given string (carefully chosen), manage the data in the code behind and when you need to send JSON data of the object apply the inverse replacement.